# Fatal Error: Index out of range - Swift 4 and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I am creating an iOS application using XCode 8 and Swift 4 that keeps track of events. I am using Firebase as my database tool for this app. I am running into an "index out of range" error in the code below. I am using a for loop to read the Event start and end times for each event in the Firebase Database. The code is able to return the event names, but not the times underneath. Why is this the case? Is there something wrong with my code, or is there something wrong with my database structure? The database structure used is pasted below the code here.

Code here:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase


class Event_List_Controller: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var eventList = [String]()
    var startTimeArray = [String]()
    var endTimeArray = [String]()

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var handle:DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        endTimeArray.removeAll()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let emailfinal = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "splicedEmailStandard")

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        handle = ref?.child(emailfinal!).child("Event Data").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.eventList.append(item)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })

        // FOR LOOP THAT POPULATES THE START AND END TIMES
        for individualEvents in eventList {
            ref = Database.database().reference()

            handle = ref?.child(emailfinal!).child("Event Data").child(individualEvents).child("Start Time").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                    self.startTimeArray.append("\(item)")
                }
            })
            handle = ref?.child(emailfinal!).child("Event Data").child(individualEvents).child("End Time").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
                    self.endTimeArray.append("\(item)")
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customClassCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.classLabel.text = eventList[indexPath.row]

        // FATAL ERROR: INDEX OUT OF RANGE HERE.
        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(startTimeArray[indexPath.row]) - \(endTimeArray[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Database Structure:

```
email@email (User)

-> User Information

----> (Information)

---> Event Information

------> Event Name

----------> Event Start Time

----------> Event End Time

----------> Event Location

email@email (User 2)

----> ...
```

Comment: Do you get information in which line you have "index out of range"? Or at least function?
Also I don't undestand your db schema? Does length of arrow mean anything?

Comment: It would help you get responses if you provided more information. Which line is the error on, for example?

Comment: Can you verify that your startTimeArray, endTimeArray and evenList array all have the same number of elements? My guess is they don't which would cause that error.  The code is a little sketchy in that it's reading data from an array based on the count of another array. Perhaps some basic error checking in the tableView:cellForRowAt with a nil coalescing operator would help; *let start = startTimeArray[indexPath.row ?? "No Start Time"*. Oh, and when does the For loop get called that populates the start and end time arrays?

Comment: All three arrays have the same number of elements once populated since there is always one start time for one event. The For loop gets called right after the events Array is populated. There are comments where the For loop gets called and where the error is. I will try to create the error checking system to see if it works.

Comment: It looks like you are appending items to the array and calling reload tableView after each append. Where in that process is the loop called - it doesn't show in the question but if you tell the tableView to update *before* that loop is called it would cause that error as the arrays will be out of sync; the event list will have an object, the tableView is refreshed but the other arrays are not populated yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling reloadData() before you're actually getting the start and end times for the events, so the startTimeArray and endTimeArray will not have objects at the index of the event you just got from firebase.

Also consider that with Firebase you're setting up observing rather than getting all of your data at once. Perhaps some simple class like Event:

```
class Event {
    var name: String
    var startTime: String
    var endTime: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.startTime = "" //or some other sensible default before loading 
        self.endTime = "" //or some other default
    }

}
```

Then have an array of Event object that your tableview is using instead of the array of strings, and update the Event objects and refresh the table view whenever you get new data in from Firebase

Comment: I will try to create an event object instead of an array.The reloadData() was a problem in my code, but fixing it did not make the error go away. Thanks!